# Prevent Azure B2C users from logging in with an email address when the username login flow is enabled

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have some custom policies setup in Azure AD B2C, one of which is a flow where the user logs in with their username. I used the following [github code](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin) for reference. My problem is that users that were previously setup using an email address can also login through the username flow by using their email address as the username. I want to prevent this.

Here are my first two `UserJourney` steps:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <Preconditions>
    <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
      <Value>objectId</Value>
      <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
    </Precondition>
  </Preconditions>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

The technical profile for `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username`.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

The `SignUpTarget` metadata is referencing `SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange` which has the technical profile of `LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName` as seen in step two of the `UserJourney`.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonName">
  <DisplayName>Username signup</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountType">Username</Item>
    <Item Key="LocalAccountProfile">true</Item>
    <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
    <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName" />
  </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

And the `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName` validation technical profile.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName">
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
  </InputClaims>
  <PersistedClaims>
    <!-- Required claims -->
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationEmailAddress" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
    <!-- Optional claims. -->
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
    <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
  </PersistedClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Here are the identities for each user:

User 1

```
"identities":[
  {
     "signInType":"emailAddress",
     "issuer":"{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
     "issuerAssignedId":"userOne@yahoo.com"
  },
  {
     "signInType":"userPrincipalName",
     "issuer":"{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
     "issuerAssignedId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com"
  }
]
```

User 2:

```
"identities":[
  {
     "signInType":"userName",
     "issuer":"{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
     "issuerAssignedId":"userTwo"
  },
  {
     "signInType":"userPrincipalName",
     "issuer":"{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com",
     "issuerAssignedId":"XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX@{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com"
  }
]
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sign in technical profile, add a validation technical profile to read the account, using signInNames.username. Configure its metadata to throw an error if the user doesn’t exist. Insert this before the login-noninteractive validation technical profile.

Solution:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-ReadUsingUsername">
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
      <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
   </Metadata>
   <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
   </InputClaims>
   <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
   </OutputClaims>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username">
...snip...
<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
   <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-ReadUsingUsername" />
   <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
...snip...
```

References:
[Understand the starter pack](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/azureadb2ccommunity.io/wiki)
[Azure AD R/W Technical Profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile)

Comment: I am not familiar with how to do this. I understand how to create a validation tech profile, but not how to throw an error using the metadata keys. And I have signInNames.username as an input claim in my AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName but I'm not sure if that is doing the "read the account, using signInNames.username" thing you are asking. I'm a little new to this.

Comment: Added complete solution. You problem is not much to do with `AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonName` other than it explains where you write the username identifier at sign up (`signInNames.username`). The default sign in technical profile matches all signInNames. Insert a read operation prior to login-noninteractive which is more explicit by reading the user by `signInNames.username` explicitly.

Comment: Ah! I see now. Good to know you can setup a `Read` then use the raise error key to throw an error if the input claim(s) doesn't exist. Thanks for the help.